# Symlink all directories under base - including new directories created. Ongoing Symlink

Tags: symlink

So i understand I could probably just use CRON to do this, because I can symlink directories under base using

```
ln -s /base/* /target
```

But just wondering if anybody knows a way to have this automatically happen. When A new directory is created under base a new symlink is created under target without re-running symlink command.

My scenario:

I have Kodi scrape a folder called TV in /target

But I have giant TV shows (over 100GB's) on a separate disk.

I want everything from

```
base/tv2/(Giant TV Shows)
```

to show under

```
/target/tv/(Gaint TV Shows)
```

Without having:

```
/target/tv/tv2(symlink)/(GiantTVShows)
```

Comment: And where should that symlink point to? If the top directory is a link, it doesn't contain any directories anyways, what you see are the directoryies of the original target.

Comment: ? I am confused by your question, but I will give a file tree example for my scenario